# Создание контакта на hubspot.com при отправке формы

Tags: php, api, drupal8

Есть кастом модуль с формой в drupal 8. Нужно сделать, чтобы при отправке формы создавался новый контакт на сайте hubspot.com. Читала документацию [url]https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/create_or_update[/url] 
Как я понимаю, нужно создать пост запрос на [url]https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/createOrUpdate/email/testingapis@hubspot.com/?hapikey=demo[/url], где подставить свой hapikey и почту заменить выражением, достающим емэйл введенный в форму. 
Выдает ошибку:
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/createOrUpdate/email/123@gmail.com/?hapikey=62c6e162-1f3e-40eb-aa07-d0a31a5aa131` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"status":"error","message":"Invalid JSON input: No content to map due to end-of-input at line 1, column 0","correlation (truncated...) in GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create() (line 113 of vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php).
**Что не так с JSON данными? Может нужно передать заголовок с указанием content-type? Помогите, пожалуйтса...**

**my_form.info.yml**

```
name: 'My Form'
description: 'Example create form in Drupal 8'
core: 8.x
type: module
```

**my_form.routing.yml**

```
my_form.example_form:
  path: '/my-form'
  defaults:
    _form:  '\Drupal\my_form\Form\MyForm'
    _title: 'My form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**MyForm.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace Drupal\my_form\Form;

    use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
    use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

    class MyForm extends FormBase {

      public $properties = [];

      public function getFormId() {
        return 'my_form';
      }


      public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['first_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'First name',
      '#required' => TRUE
    );
    $form['last_name'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Last name',
      '#required' => TRUE
    );
    $form['subject'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Subject',
      '#required' => TRUE
    );
    $form['message'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => 'Message',
      '#required' => TRUE
    );
    $form['email'] = array(
      '#type' => 'email',
      '#title' => $this->t('Your e-mail address'),
      '#required' => TRUE
    );
    $form['button'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Submit'
    );
  return $form;
      }

      public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        if (strpos($form_state->getValue('email'), '.com') === FALSE) {

           $form_state->setErrorByName('email', 'E-mail is incorrect!');

        }

      }

     public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        $message = $form_state->getValue('message');

        $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

        $subject = $form_state->getValue('subject');

        $res = mail('admin@mail.ru', $subject, $message);

        if($res) {

            \Drupal::logger('my_form')->notice('Mail is sent. E-mail: '.$form_state->getValue('email'));

            drupal_set_message('E-mail is sent!');

        }

    $email = $form_state->getValue('email');

    $url = "https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/createOrUpdate/email/".$email."/?hapikey=62c6e162-1f3e-40eb-aa07-d0a31a5aa131";

    $json = '{
  "properties": [
    {
      "property": "firstname",
      "value": "HubSpot"
    },
    {
      "property": "lastname",
      "value": "Test"
    },
    {
      "property": "website",
      "value": "http://hubspot.com"
    },
    {
      "property": "company",
      "value": "HubSpot"
    },
    {
      "property": "phone",
      "value": "555-122-2323"
    },
    {
      "property": "address",
      "value": "25 First Street"
    },
    {
      "property": "city",
      "value": "Cambridge"
    },
    {
      "property": "state",
      "value": "MA"
    },
    {
      "property": "zip",
      "value": "02139"
    }
  ]
}';

$request = \Drupal::httpClient()->post($url, NULL, $json);

try {
  $response = $request->send();
}
catch (\Guzzle\Http\Exception\RequestException $exception) {
  // ...
}

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

вопрос решен

```
    $email = $form_state->getValue('email');
    $firstname = $form_state->getValue('first_name');
    $lastname = $form_state->getValue('last_name');


    $url = "https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/createOrUpdate/email/".$email."/?hapikey=62c6e162-1f3e-40eb-aa07-************";

    $data = array(
      'properties' => [
        [
          'property' => 'firstname',
          'value' => $firstname
        ],
        [
          'property' => 'lastname',
          'value' => $lastname 
        ]
      ]
    );


    $json = json_encode($data,true);

    $response = \Drupal::httpClient()->post($url.'&_format=hal_json', [
      'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
      ],
        'body' => $json
    ]);
```